# permanent links are working but /%postname%/ not

Tags: wordpress, permalinks, apache2.4

Default permanent links are working fine, but when I try to change it to `/%postname%/` or any other type,  It is showing the following error.

Anyone have an idea why it is happening..?
Server : ubuntu 20.04

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Add the following code in your .htaccess file:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Comment: with this code permanent link is in shape : domainname.com\index\.php\postname
whereas I required domain. com//%postname%//

Comment: Sorry for delay reply  . Just remove /index.php from that code and then inform me.